# Is there any benefit for initializing an array with a predefined size for this problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was working through a coding interview problem which I believe I solved with the most optimal solution. I was comparing my code with the site's solution and noticed that they went about it a bit differently than I did.

Problem:
Write a function that takes in a non-empty array of integers that are sorted in ascending order and returns a new array of the same length with the squares of the original integers also sorted in ascending order.

My Solution:

```
def sortedSquaredArray(array):
    sml = 0
    lrg = len(array)-1
    res = []
    while len(res) != len(array):
        if abs(array[sml]) < abs(array[lrg]):
            res.append(array[lrg]**2)
            lrg -= 1
        else:
            res.append(array[sml]**2)
            sml +=1
    res.reverse()       
    return res
```

Their Solution:

```
def sortedSquaredArray(array):
    res = [0 for _ in array]
    sml = 0
    lrg = len(array)-1
    
    for idx in reversed(range(len(array))):
        smallerValue = array[sml]
        largerValue = array[lrg]
        
        if abs(smallerValue) > abs(largerValue):
            res[idx] = smallerValue * smallerValue
            sml += 1
        else
            res[idx] = largerValue * largerValue
            lrg -=1

return res
```

If I'm not mistaken, both solutions are O(n) time and O(n) space. Is there a benefit to approaching this problem as they did? I guess it may make the code more readable and doesn't require them to reverse the list as I did, but reverse() is also O(n) so that shouldn't affect the algorithm that significantly, right?

Comment: If you know the final size of an array you should initialize it. This way only once memory is allocated from the system. A dynamic growing array, as you used it, might need internal reallocation of memory or at least multiple allocations because the final size is unknown to the system. I highly recommend: You should simply profile the difference. This might also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599351/1921273

Comment: Yes, if you know in advance the dimension of the array, as in your case, better to allocate at once all the needed memory, because it is a time consuming operation. I executed the two codes in my computer using as input my_list = list(range(0, int(1e7))) and I got 4.9s for your implementation and 2.4s for the original one.

Comment: @Luca I appreciate your explanation, that is a huge difference. Thank you

Comment: @MrSmith42 Can you put your comment as an answer?